# How to optimise this code of sorting,this is not exeuting within the time limits.This question is from hackerrank

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

How to reduce the time compexity of this code,this is not exeuting within the time

exact ques from hackerrank--

Complete the circularArrayRotation function in the editor below. **It should return an array of integers representing the values at the specified indices.**

circularArrayRotation has the following parameter(s):

a: an array of integers to rotate

k: an integer, the rotation count

queries: an array of integers, the indices to report

```
   vector<int> circularArrayRotation(vector<int> a, int k, vector<int> queries) {
           int i,temp;
           vector<int> ans;
           //to perform number of queries k
            while(k--)
            {  //shift last element to first pos and then move rest of elements to 1 postion forward
                temp=a[a.size()-1];   //last element
                for(i=a.size()-1;i>0;i--)
                {
                    a[i]=a[i-1];
                }
                a[0]=temp;
                
            }
            
            for(i=0;i<queries.size();i++)
            {
                ans.push_back(a[queries[i]]);
            }
            return ans;
        }
```

Comment: You need to get the right *algorithm* first, before you write any code.

Comment: You should explain what the problem is exactly

Comment: @Damien  the problem is..i have to rotate the vector a k times ,then return the value at  the i.th postion of vector a and i belongs to vector queries,in short vector queries contains the postition (index value)of elements. and for each index value ,i have to show(or store in another vector) the corresponding value in vector a which was rotated k times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector `a` is being rotated by `k` in the while loop. The whole loop can be removed by adding `k` and using modulo when accessing elements in `a`:

```
ans.push_back(a[(queries[i]+k)%a.size()]);
```

Note: you might need handling of negative values of `k`.

Note: Maybe it should be minus instead of plus.

An alternative could be to use std::rotate.

Furthermore, the `ans` vector should be pre-allocated to reduce the number of allocations to one:

```
ans.reserve(queries.size());
```

Comment: the problem is..i have to rotate the vector a k times ,then return the value at the i.th postion of vector a and i belongs to vector queries,in short vector queries contains the postition (index value)of elements. and for each index value i have to show(or store in another vector) the corresponding value in vector a which was rotated k times

Comment: This should work effectively, ... with a minus !